# How to maintain the order of records in Salesforce Bulk Api

Tags: api

I am using Salesforce Bulk Push API to push all my accounts to account in salesforce. My doubt is how to map my account entity(my entityid) with salesforce entity.I have 10 batches. Will the order of salesforce id returned for accounts be same .

Answer (score 0):

If you have to maintain the order of insertion then use Bulk API with concurrency mode as **Serial**. In that case, it will process your data in a serial manner.

For more information, refer [Loading Large Data Sets with the Force.com Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Loading_Large_Data_Sets_with_the_Force.com_Bulk_API)